# trigger viewDidAppear in extension or how to use variable from extension in viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewdidappear

Hi I want to put the viewDidAppear in my extension, but it cannot be triggered...

see the code:

```
extension MyAutoWelcomViewController: VehicleMangerDelegate {
    
    
    func didUpdateRdwInfo(rdwData: RdwModel) {
        
    }
    
    func didUpdateVehicleInfo(vehicle: VehicleModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // code to pass data to a label
            print(vehicle.numberOfVehicles)
            
            let numberOfVehilce = vehicle.numberOfVehicles
            self.TestLabel.text = String(numberOfVehilce)

            func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                
                self.vehicleManager.delegate = self
                
                // check if vehicle list is nil
                
                self.vehicleManager.getVehicleData() // call api to get the user vehicle list
                
                if numberOfVehilce == 0 {
                    // show the welcome screen
                    print("vehicleList is nil")
                    
                } else {
                    // use segue to navigate to the auto list screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueMyAutoWelcomeToAutoList, sender: self)
                    print("vehicleList is not nil")
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }

    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

The reason that I want to do this is because I have used a delegate (`VehicleMangerDelegate`) to pass some data from another screen to here, in the `didUpdateVehicleInfo()`function.

Can you help me on this? I need to trigger the **performSegue** based on the data from an API call (i.e., `numberOfVehicle`), and the data is passed to this screen using a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your real real question, it is that you want to use `numberOfVehilce` in `viewDidAppear`, but you want to declare that variable in your extension.

The problem with this is that extensions cannot add stored properties to the classes they extend; if you tried to declare that variable as a property outside your delegate function you would have gotten an error from the compiler.

To work around this you made it a local variable in the function.

Now your problem is that your `viewDidAppear` function can't see that variable as it is out of scope.  You then created 'viewDidAppear` as an internal function so that it *could* see the variable.

This won't work for you though since you aren't declaring the view controller's 'viewDidAppear`that is visible to the`UIKit` framework,  but rather an internal function to your delegate function that just happens to have the same name.

You will need to declare `numberOfVehicle` as a property in your view controller itself, not in the extension. Then you can refer to it both in your delegate method and in `viewDidAppear`.

```
class MyAutoWelcomViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOfVehicle = 0

    func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                
                self.vehicleManager.delegate = self
                
                // check if vehicle list is nil
                
                self.vehicleManager.getVehicleData() // call api to get the user vehicle list
                
                if numberOfVehilce == 0 {
                    // show the welcome screen
                    print("vehicleList is nil")
                    
                } else {
                    // use segue to navigate to the auto list screen
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.segueMyAutoWelcomeToAutoList, sender: self)
                    print("vehicleList is not nil")
                }
                
            }
    }

}

    extension MyAutoWelcomViewController: VehicleMangerDelegate {
    
    
    func didUpdateRdwInfo(rdwData: RdwModel) {
        
    }
    
    func didUpdateVehicleInfo(vehicle: VehicleModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // code to pass data to a label
            print(vehicle.numberOfVehicles)
            
            self.numberOfVehilce = vehicle.numberOfVehicles
            self.TestLabel.text = String(numberOfVehilce)
    }
```

I still have a concern however; you have not shown what `getVehicleData` does, but it refers to an API.  If it executes asynchronously to fetch data and calls the delegate, then your code will not work as intended since `viewDidAppear` will have finished executing before the delegate method is called. You probably need to perform the segue in your delegate function.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks Paulw11 !!!!

You not only pointed out my lacking knowledge on extension in a easy-to-understand way. Now I completely get. I tried to declare a local variable, at least no errors. And I leant how to deal with such situation in the future.

And your concern is correct, the viewDidAppear is executed faster than the delegate method. Moving the segue to the delegate function solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How It should work? You are defining local function inside block of code, it is not `viewDidApear` from VC. You shouldn't trigger view controller lifecycle methods by your own, system does it if needed. You have to rethink Your code. If You are fresh to iOS development, find [Stanford course on Youtube](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu).

Comment: Thanks Prettygeek,

Do you know how can I move the variable in an extension to be used in my UIViewcontroller? i.e., how can I use the variable in my viewDidAppear function?

Comment: This community wil not replace learning and will not code for you, I gave you materials.

Comment: Appreciate your material, however...

I am asking in Stackoverflow because I want to get the problem solved, not to get suggestions which course should take. You don't need to code for me, I just need some hints. I can then figure it out myself. Your answer is too general, which has little help. Sorry Prettygeek. If no one answer my question here, I will figure it out myself, and accept my own answer. 

The reason is simple, I don't want someone in the future googled this question, click in, and see the accepted answer is to take a course.